# Laravel: Declaration must be compatible with StructureController->store(request: \Illuminate\Http\Request)

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-9, php-8

I have an abstract class called StructureController

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repository\StructureRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

abstract class StructureController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->copy($request);
        $data = json_encode(safeArray($request->toArray()));
        $this->structureRepository->publish($this->structureKey, $data);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', __('messages.Content published successfully'));
    }
}
```

and have a child controller extends StructureController, called ContactUsController

```
class ContactUsController extends StructureController
{    
    public function store(ContactUsRequest $request) { // ERROR IS HERE
        return parent::store($request);
    }
}
```

I want to override the request class to make different validation for every child class and it gives me this error:

> Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Structure\ContactUsController::store(App\Http\Requests\Dashboard\Structure\ContactUsRequest $request) must be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Structure\StructureController::store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)

Comment: Why they are not the same? "ContactUsRequest" type is FormReuest which extends Request class!
I will use the StructureController as a parent for many other controllers with same methods.. so I want to make different validation for each child controller. @PaulT.

Comment: that error is at the declaration of the method level not at the call level ... you could rename the parent's `store` method and have all the children's `store` methods call that renamed method

Comment: @AmeerAhmed, have you solved this issue? I'm having the same problem so I'm hoping to find an answer. Thank you in advance

Comment: @lagbox Yes, I made the method in the parent class named '_store()' and in the child named 'store()' and its body:
return parent::_store($request);